# Object is of type 'unknown' - forEach and map

Tags: typescript

I am doing a loop on an Object using `forEach` or `map`.
However, I am getting a type error on the variable that I use to loop.
The error is `Object is of type 'unknown'.`

This occurs on `val.name`, `val.title`.

**With .forEach**

```
    Object.entries(data).forEach(
      ([, val]) => {
        newObject[val.name] = { // Object is of type 'unknown'
          title: val.title // Object is of type 'unknown'
        }}
      )
```

**With .map**

```
Object.entries(data).map(
  ([, val]) => {
    newObject[val.name] = { // Object is of type 'unknown'
      title: val.title // Object is of type 'unknown'
    }}
  )
```

I tried to specify a type on the variable `val` such as:

```
([, val: any]) => {..my code..}
```

but it does not accept a type in that position

Answer (score 5):

I found the same problem, finally I just replace [k, v] by (k, v: any)

```
Object.entries(obj).forEach((key, value: any) => {console.log(key, " => ", value);});
```

Answer (score 4):

One answer is to go back to the "classic" way of iterating object properties in JavaScript, before `Object.entries()` existed, like so:

```
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
}
for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
  const value = obj[k]
  // Do something with 'value'...
}
```

This works because the type of `value` is `any` instead of the much more restrictive `unknown` that comes from using `Object.entries()`.  This was tested and works in TypeScript v4.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.entries<any>
```

use like this, the value will be any in this case