# How to assign type to [key, value] in a forEach loop

Tags: typescript

I'm currently getting a typescript syntax error in my project saying the `prodStatus` needs to be defined...

```
const products = {
    1: {isUpdating: false, qty: 2},
    2: {isUpdating: true, qty: 4}
}
const updatingProducts: Array<{id: number; prodStatus: {isUpdating: boolean; qty: number}}> = [];
Object.entries(products).forEach(([prodId, prodStatus]) => {
  if (prodStatus.isUpdating) {
    updatingProducts.push({id: Number(prodId), prodStatus: prodStatus});
  }
});
```

It's currently erroring out for me both on the `if(prodStatus.isUpdating)` and the key `prodStatus` in the `push`. Perhaps because in my code on the actual project I'm importing the variable `products`, and typescript needs to know the type for `prodStatus`?

Anyone know how to assign `[prodId, prodStatus]` a type?

**NOTE**: in the file I'm importing the `products` variable, it looks like this(in reactjs)...

```
const products = useRef<{[key: string]: {isUpdating: boolean; qty: number}}>({});
```

UPDATE: tried solution and updating screenshot with error...
[image]

Comment: what error does typescript give you?

Comment: @NicolaScionti for the if statement... Line1:"(parameter) prodStatus: unknown", line2: "Object is of type 'unknown'."

Comment: Have you tried `Object.entries(products).forEach(([prodId, prodStatus]: [string, {isUpdating: boolean; qty: number}]) => { ...`? Does it work for you?

Answer (score 2):

`Object.entries` gives you a `[key, value]`, where `key` is always a string. Then you should be fine with:

```
Object.entries(products).forEach(([prodId, prodStatus]: [string, {isUpdating: boolean, qty: number}]) => {
  if (prodStatus.isUpdating) {
    updatingProducts.push({ id: Number(prodId), prodStatus: prodStatus });
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm still getting the error: `Argument of type '([prodId, prodStatus]: [string, {isUpdating: boolean, qty: number}]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: [string, unknown], index: number, array: [string, unknown][]) => void'.
  Types of parameters '__0' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type '[string, unknown]' is not assignable to type '[string, {isUpdating: boolean, qty: number}]'.
      Type at position 1 in source is not compatible with type at position 1 in target.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '{isUpdating: boolean, qty: number}'.`

Comment: I've also tried `forEach(([prodId, prodStatus]: [prodId: string, prodStatus: {isUpdating: boolean, qty: number}]) ...`, which didn't work. I updated a screenshot in the question so you could see.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62920091/object-is-of-type-unknown-foreach-and-map and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838835/typescript-3-x-access-properties-of-type-unknown if something helps you

Comment: I saw the first one earlier and was hoping for a way to allow me to utilize javascripts destructuring of key/value pairing while looping through an object. But it doesn't look like it. I suppose I'll add this to my list of reasons I dislike typescript. Thanks again for all the effort. +1

Comment: lol, it's cheap, but it looks like this is working... `forEach(([prodId, prodStatus]: any)`